# Correct design for binding data to a XAML control in a view, from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

For context, I am building a universal Windows Store app.

I'm just starting to learn C# and MVVM patterns and I need help correctly implementing binding.

I have followed this tutorial (Binding) and understand how it works, however in this example the code which does the binding is stored within the View Class.

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
public ObservableCollection<TermTest> MyTerms = new ObservableCollection<TermTest>();
public MainPage()
{ 
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyTerms.Add(new TermTest("BNC", "Wire"));
    MyTerms.Add(new TermTest("Lens", "Collects light"));
    this.DataContext = new CollectionViewSource { Source = MyTerms }; 
}
```

As I understand it however this is poor design. In my implementation I will be using my Model to retrieve data which will get put into an Observable Collection. Then in my ViewModel I will want to bind the ObservableCollection to the XAML controls in which it is being used, not send the Collection to the View and then call a method in the View to populate the XAML controls.

Is that the correct way of doing this and, if so, how should it be done because I do not know how to expose the XAML controls to my ViewModel (and don't think I should be, right?).

I know I can expose the control creating a new instance of Mainpage but that is useless as I would need to bind to the current instance.

```
Mainpage Test = new MainPage();
```

Can someone please help me explain this - I have been through a lot reading and either not found the answer or not understood it!

Thanks, James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin, you definitely have the right idea.

What you want to do is create a ViewModel *object* (have it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) something like:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INPC implementation

    public ObservableCollection<TermTest> MyTerms
    {
       //Standard INPC property stuff
    }
}
```

Note that I used a property. You can only bind to properties, and you'll need the set method to raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Then, you set the data context for the view. You can do this a number of ways, but the simplest is to do this:

```
public MainView() //Default Constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Finally, bind!

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyTerms}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you don't want to touch the code behind of your window, you can do something like this:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <YourNamespace:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
        <ListView x:Name="TermsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTerms}">    
        </ListView>
   </Grid>
```

If you want understand in details this pattern I recommend you read this article:[WPF MVVM step by step (Basics to Advance Level)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

Comment: Make sure to add `YourNamespace` as an xmlns for this. A good approach for declaring your view model though!